# iPhone view not reseting after keyboard hides

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard-events

I was using a example for a book to slide the view up as the keyboard shows up for it not to cover up the text fields.

Everything works except for the fact that my view slides up and does not slide down if i click on the background to hide the keyboard. The keyboard hides but the view stays shifted up. If I use the return key to hide the keyboard everything works fine. The following is my code:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif {
    NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];
    NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:
                       UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;
    float bottomPoint = (password.frame.origin.y+
                         password.frame.size.height+10);

    scrollAmount = keyboardSize.height -
    (self.view.frame.size.height- bottomPoint);
    if (scrollAmount > 0) {
        moveViewUp = YES;
        [self scrollTheView:YES];
    }
    else
        moveViewUp = NO;
}
- (void)scrollTheView:(BOOL)movedUp {
    [UIControl beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIControl setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (movedUp){
        rect.origin.y -= scrollAmount;
    }
    else {
        rect.origin.y += scrollAmount;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;
    [UIControl commitAnimations];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    if (moveViewUp) [self scrollTheView:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

I am having a tough time figuring out why the view what animate down after the keyboard is hidden when touching the background to hide the keyboard

Once again any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that when you click on the background(not on done) that it fires you textFieldShouldReturn method?

Comment: Hmm I should I have checked this early. It does not fire my textFieldShouldReturn method. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `textFieldShouldReturn` method is only called when you hit the return button on the keyboard.  To catch all kinds of keyboard disappearance, use `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

Another approach is to register for `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` as well as `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'UIControl' in your animation statements to 'UIView'.